# Mongo DB connects successful but does not create database

Tags: mongodb

```
const express = require('express');
const exphbs = require('express-handlebars');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const app = express();

// Connect to mongoose
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/sample')
.then(() => console.log('MongoDB Connected...'))
.catch(err => console.log(err));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
const title = 'Welcome';
res.send('ok');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
   console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});
```

I have written this code to connect MongoDB and there is no issue with the connection but when I show my DBS using "> show dbs", I can't see the sample database which I have created. My system is windows 32 bit.
[image]

Comment: It may not create your DB until you create a doc or an index in a collection. Are you doing that somewhere else?

Comment: No, I have just created the dbs and try to show the dbs but can't see

Comment: So, have I to create the collection?

Comment: No, but you do have to add something to the db, like save a new document.

Comment: ok, I will save some document.

Comment: Thank you so much. It works

Answer (score 0):

Just connecting to the database won't create it. You need to add something to the database like saving a new document or adding an index.